# how check if the row don't exist on the other table while using LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql, oracle

i have 2 tables and i left join them , i want to add extra dummy column 
to check if that row doesn't exist on the right table

this table A

```
TableID|TableName
   0     table 1
   1     table 2
   2     table 3
```

and this the table B

```
TableName|isSuper
table 1     0
table 2     1
```

and i use this query to left join them

```
SELECT A.TABLE_NAME, NVL(B.IsSUper|,0)
  FROM    A
LEFT JOIN B on A.TableName=B.TableName
```

and the result will be

```
TableName| isSuper
 table1      0
 table2      1
 table3      0
```

i want to add extra dummy value to check if that row existed in table b like that

```
TableName| isSuper | existedOnB
     table1      0        1
     table2      1        1
     table3      0        0
```

how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

I think simple `case` expression is enough to check row exists or not and put `1` or `0`

```
SELECT 
      a.TABLE_NAME, 
      NVL(B.IsSUper, 0) isSuper,
      CASE WHEN B.IsSUper IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END existedOnB
FROM  tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b on a.TableName = b.TableName
```

Answer (score 1):

One option uses a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    A.TABLE_NAME,
    NVL(B.IsSuper, 0),
    CASE WHEN B.IsSuper IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS existedOnB
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
    ON A.TableName = B.TableName
```

The marker for a record in table `A` which did not match to anything in `B` would be that any of the `B` fields would be `NULL`.  So we may check for this condition using a `CASE` expression.